# Get Tweets and Auth Header in Axois

Tags: node.js, twitter, axios, twitter-oauth

Get user Tweets From Timeline - Call Twitter API using Axios
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

its Failed to Authorize the Header

Here is my Code

```
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();


var apiurl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nodejs&count=5';

const client = {
    consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMERKEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMERSECRET,
    bearer_token: process.env.BEARERETOKEN
};

async function go() {

    try {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        const wes = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            auth: client,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            url: apiurl
        });
        var getweets = wes.data;
        console.log(getweets);

        const group = getweets.tweets.map(g => [
            g.text
        ]);

        var data = JSON.stringify(group, null, 2);
        console.log(data.replace(/\[|\]|"|,/g, ''));

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
go();
```

I want to get the User's Timeline Tweets

Comment: Where did you get this code from? The docs dont have any info on a parameter called `consumer_secret` ?

Comment: sorry for my bad code I follow the `NPM` twitter module code pattern it requires authentication

Comment: You can grab TinyTwitter